# Запуск .exe приложения с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, windows

У меня есть сайт и приложение на windows. Как я могу запустить приложение через сайт нажатием кнопки? Это возможно, т.к. в Zoom это реализовано. Как я понял, они в реестре зарегистрировали zoom и вызывают через uri. Как регистрировать я нашел информацию, но не понимаю, как вызвать через js
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: также как и ссылки `href="mailto: .... "` и `tel:, callto:, sms:`, видимо

Comment: @teran есть рабочий пример?

Comment: [Если правильно понял, то вот тут ответы.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыть URL c собственной схемой можно так же, как открыть обычный URL:

```
window.open("myapp:...","_self")
```

или

```
location.href = "myapp:...";
```

Comment: Это на клиенте или сервере?